# Is there a way to find and replace HTML markup in Visual Studio Editor?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use find and replace to remove scripts from an HTML document.  I tried to use the following regular expression, but it only selects script beginning and end tag, but leaves tag's content in place:

```
"</?script[^<]*?>"
```

For the record, I am not versed in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/974369) which addresses parsing HTML using regex.  Try using something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead which does the work of parsing for you, and allows you to query the file using XPath.